# (How) Should I mention I might need days off during interview?

Tags: interviewing, vacation, benefits

I am currently searching for a full-time job, both for income and benefits. I have a couple job interviews already, however I also just finished applying to a large number of graduate schools throughout the country for Fall 2015 admission. I should start hearing back about interview offers for the different programs over the next few weeks. I anticipate these would take place February-March. I anticipate I'd need 1-2 days each.

If I am extended a job offer, should I bring up the fact I might need to take days off so soon after beginning? If so, how should I go about it? After March, I would be able to work without interruption until (hopefully) I start my graduate studies in August.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What about bringing up that you just want to work until the fall? That is, you're really looking for a temporary job.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Well, if I don't get into a program, I would be working for longer.

Comment: This is asked very often.  Mention pre-planned time off when they offer the job and have a start date.  It is possible that the start date will be after the time off, thus they don't need to know (or care to know).  If it is close, like the week after you start, maybe delay starting.  But, at any rate, mention it when they give you an offer and start date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think Jivan's answer is incorrect. I think it's good.

But I do believe an equally valid counter argument is to just worry about getting the job. If you get to the point where they make an offer, that's when you can negotiate additional time off if need be. Don't give your employer silly reasons to scratch you off the candidate list early. Find out if you're a good match and they want you. If they do, then they'll be a lot more open to offering you some concessions at the point of offer signing.

I don't think that will cost you any 'trust' points. It's merely part of the typical offer negotiation process. They make an offer, you simply are asking for some additional time off as a counter-offer.

Comment: This is kind of what I am thinking. I tend not to get the cart before the horse, but I have a good feeling about the jobs considering the precise experience requirements and area in which they are located. I will certainly be

Comment: putting my main effort into getting the job offer as a whole; I just was afraid of either appearing disingenuous or hurting my chances overall by presenting the circumstances in a less than optimal manner. So, I should go about the interview as normal, and if things feel like a good match and an offer is made, I can then present my own stipulations. I'm leaning toward this route, I think. Thanks for the help! 

*sorry for the double post. Accidentally pressed enter instead of shift+enter and it wouldn't let me edit after 5 mins*

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of possible answers, but one way to consider your question is to look at it as a matter of giving your profile a **strong perceived value**.

Try to take your potential employer's place. Why would he be willing to hire a person that he knows will be partially off just after the beginning of his contract? One way to raise your chances is the following.

**Build a maximum of trust** during the different interviews you'll go through. And don't wait for the last one to announce your point. Instead, wait for the moment where you'll feel in the strongest possible position. Pick one moment when you feel you scored a lot of points and just go for it naturally like "oh, I have to mention...".

Basically if the employer feels that you can be/become a strong a reliable asset, he won't bother at all giving you some days off for educational purposes. Just put it on the table at the right moment.